# calculation of the total response time using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, httpresponse, performance-testing

I ran a test and generated various reports using the listeners. but am confused how to calculate the total response time for the test that has run. have attached the screenshots.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU6RA.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a total response time of all the requests of the test? Are all these requests related to 1 transaction? (!!)

1) In that case, You can place all the requests under a `Transaction Controller`. This will give you the total time of all the requests placed under Transaction Controller.

2) You can calculate the total response time by using Beanshell listener.

3) Write the results in CSV file and you can calculate the sum.

In your case, each and every samples made only one request. So total time would be Average * (No of Samples) = 448 ms